# how to prevent formatting (i.e., erasing) of flash drive

Tags: hard-drive, formatting, flash

How do I prevent someone who’s up to no good from formatting (i.e., deleting the files from) my flash drive on my PC?

You see, I have security cameras that send footage to a flash drive connected to my PC, and from that drive the footage is automatically uploaded to the cloud. But if the footage gets erased from the drive, it disappears from the cloud too. So I'm looking for a way to prevent a burglar, who finds my computer and flash drive (with his or her incriminated face in one of the files on that drive), from formatting the drive and thereby simply deleting the files from it. If he or she does that, my security system is defeated.

I just spent 3 hours encrypting the flash drive with Veracrypt, and afterward, when I unplugged and then plugged the drive back in to my PC, Windows asked me if I wanted to format it. Hoping it would fail, I clicked "Yes."

And that was that—wiped clean, encryption useless.

Also, my video files sync to OneDrive, and my understanding is that there is no way to set up OneDrive so the files will stay there once they're deleted from my flash drive.

Am I wrong? Or is there a different cloud service that will allow me to keep files there if they are deleted from my flash drive

Comment: Enable remote access to the computer, remove all keyboards and mice and then superglue plastic wedges into all but one of the USB ports, then superglue the memory stick into the final port.

Comment: Essentially though the moment someone has physical access to a machine you should consider it already compromised. Heck a burglar could simply remove the power cord to stop uploads and then take the computer with them. The moment they walk through your door and see the computer then you have already lost.

Comment: Why won't you simply set up your system in a way that the footage wont get deleted from the cloud?

Comment: “So I'm looking for a way to prevent a burglar, who finds my computer and flash drive (with his or her incriminated face in one of the files on that drive), from formatting the drive and thereby simply deleting the files from it.” Where do you get the idea that someone breaking into your home will somehow get to your PC and format it? Won’t they just steal the PC itself? And if they steal the PC, they will just wipe the drive — if they can’t get data off of it — and that means your OneDrive files are safe since they will effectively disable the OneDrive connection between the PC and OneCloud.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Physical access to the drive means it can be wiped.

USB drives are for convenience, not safe backup.

The correct way to protect files from malicious deletion is to place them in multiple unique locations others do not have access to, or permission to access.